# Jar to exe using NSIS

Tags: jar, nsis

so I seeking for a program (which is free) that will allow me to make from jar to exe with wrapping JRE also... til now I used Launch4J and I tried out others also but I found NSIS which is much more powerful and i think will fit what I'm looking for, but I'm having problems with defining CLASSPATH and CLASS.

Here's the code:

```
Name "Tool"
Caption "Internal"
Icon "UIT.ico"
OutFile "Tool.exe"

VIAddVersionKey "ProductName" "Tool"
VIAddVersionKey "Comments" "Internal"
VIAddVersionKey "CompanyName" ""
VIAddVersionKey "LegalTrademarks" ""
VIAddVersionKey "LegalCopyright" ""
VIAddVersionKey "FileDescription" "Tool"
VIAddVersionKey "FileVersion" "3.0.1934"
VIProductVersion 3.0.1934"

!define CLASSPATH "ApplicationTool.jar"
!define CLASS "v3build1934"
!define PRODUCT_NAME "Tool"

; Definitions for Java 8.0
!define JRE_VERSION "8.0"
!define JRE_URL "http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=24936&/jre-6u10-windows-i586-p.exe"
;!define JRE_VERSION "8.0"
;!define JRE_URL "http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=22933&/jre-1_5_0_16-windows-i586-p.exe"

; use javaw.exe to avoid dosbox.
; use java.exe to keep stdout/stderr
!define JAVAEXE "javaw.exe"

RequestExecutionLevel user
SilentInstall silent
AutoCloseWindow true
ShowInstDetails nevershow

!include "FileFunc.nsh"
!insertmacro GetFileVersion
!insertmacro GetParameters
!include "WordFunc.nsh"
!insertmacro VersionCompare
!include "UAC.nsh"

Section ""
  Call GetJRE
  Pop $R0

  ; change for your purpose (-jar etc.)
  ${GetParameters} $1
  StrCpy $0 '"$R0" -classpath "${CLASSPATH}" ${CLASS} $1'

  SetOutPath $EXEDIR
  Exec $0
SectionEnd

;  returns the full path of a valid java.exe
;  looks in:
;  1 - .\jre directory (JRE Installed with application)
;  2 - JAVA_HOME environment variable
;  3 - the registry
;  4 - hopes it is in current dir or PATH
Function GetJRE
    Push $R0
    Push $R1
    Push $2

  ; 1) Check local JRE
  CheckLocal:
    ClearErrors
    StrCpy $R0 "$EXEDIR\pkg\bin\${JAVAEXE}"
    IfFileExists $R0 JreFound

  ; 2) Check for JAVA_HOME
  CheckJavaHome:
    ClearErrors
    ReadEnvStr $R0 "JAVA_HOME"
    StrCpy $R0 "$R0\bin\${JAVAEXE}"
    IfErrors CheckRegistry     
    IfFileExists $R0 0 CheckRegistry
    Call CheckJREVersion
    IfErrors CheckRegistry JreFound

  ; 3) Check for registry
  CheckRegistry:
    ClearErrors
    ReadRegStr $R1 HKLM "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" "CurrentVersion"
    ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\$R1" "JavaHome"
    StrCpy $R0 "$R0\bin\${JAVAEXE}"
    IfErrors DownloadJRE
    IfFileExists $R0 0 DownloadJRE
    Call CheckJREVersion
    IfErrors DownloadJRE JreFound

  DownloadJRE:
    Call ElevateToAdmin
    MessageBox MB_ICONINFORMATION "${PRODUCT_NAME} uses Java Runtime Environment ${JRE_VERSION}, it will now be downloaded and installed."
    StrCpy $2 "$TEMP\Java Runtime Environment.exe"
    nsisdl::download /TIMEOUT=30000 ${JRE_URL} $2
    Pop $R0 ;Get the return value
    StrCmp $R0 "success" +3
      MessageBox MB_ICONSTOP "Download failed: $R0"
      Abort
    ExecWait $2
    Delete $2

    ReadRegStr $R1 HKLM "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" "CurrentVersion"
    ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\$R1" "JavaHome"
    StrCpy $R0 "$R0\bin\${JAVAEXE}"
    IfFileExists $R0 0 GoodLuck
    Call CheckJREVersion
    IfErrors GoodLuck JreFound

  ; 4) wishing you good luck
  GoodLuck:
    StrCpy $R0 "${JAVAEXE}"
    ; MessageBox MB_ICONSTOP "Cannot find appropriate Java Runtime Environment."
    ; Abort

  JreFound:
    Pop $2
    Pop $R1
    Exch $R0
FunctionEnd

; Pass the "javaw.exe" path by $R0
Function CheckJREVersion
    Push $R1

    ; Get the file version of javaw.exe
    ${GetFileVersion} $R0 $R1
    ${VersionCompare} ${JRE_VERSION} $R1 $R1

    ; Check whether $R1 != "1"
    ClearErrors
    StrCmp $R1 "1" 0 CheckDone
    SetErrors

  CheckDone:
    Pop $R1
FunctionEnd

; Attempt to give the UAC plug-in a user process and an admin process.
Function ElevateToAdmin
  UAC_Elevate:
    !insertmacro UAC_RunElevated
    StrCmp 1223 $0 UAC_ElevationAborted ; UAC dialog aborted by user?
    StrCmp 0 $0 0 UAC_Err ; Error?
    StrCmp 1 $1 0 UAC_Success ;Are we the real deal or just the wrapper?
    Quit

  UAC_ElevationAborted:
    # elevation was aborted, run as normal?
    MessageBox MB_ICONSTOP "This installer requires admin access, aborting!"
    Abort

  UAC_Err:
    MessageBox MB_ICONSTOP "Unable to elevate, error $0"
    Abort

  UAC_Success:
    StrCmp 1 $3 +4 ;Admin?
    StrCmp 3 $1 0 UAC_ElevationAborted ;Try again?
    MessageBox MB_ICONSTOP "This installer requires admin access, try again"
    goto UAC_Elevate 
FunctionEnd
```

What do i need to put in those 2 or should I move the script somewhere else for example where the netbeans project is ???

Comment: The example code is pretty useless, since there's no indication about your intention. Why did you define these, where and how will you use them? Please post the relevant portions of your script.

Comment: I edited my post, the thing is I need to elevate the application or to request for elevation when privileges are required. With Launch4j I was using a build.manifest, but I really don't know how to create those, and i need some sort of workaround till I catch up with that.

Comment: The UAC plug-in is NOT used to elevate! It is used to "undo" the elevation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set environment variables for the NSIS process and child processes by calling [SetEnvironmentVariable](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Setting_Environment_Variables):

```
System::Call 'Kernel32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t "CLASSPATH", t "c:\some\path\you\got\from\the\registry")'
```